# Checking resources which have not loaded

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<body>

<img src="">//resource 1

<a href="">//resource 2

<script>

window.onload =function () {// code logic here}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to check which resources gave an error such as "resource not found" after the window.onload. Or is there a way by which I can extract the errors from developer tools.

Comment: In firebug "NET" tab shows you the status.

Answer (score 0):

below code will give you syntax error brace `}`.

```
window.onload =function () {// code logic here}
```

replace

```
window.onload =function () 
{
  // code logic here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the browser's developer tools is the right choice here. Chrome Developer Tools has a Network tab which will timeline requests from the browser, and inform you if any requests failed.

Note the asset highlighted in red in the below screenshot.

[image: Chrome developer tools]

Comment: Why the downvote? His question specifies: "there a way by which I can extract the errors from developer tools." - Chrome Developer Tools will show you which resource requests failed.